# Redirecting stdout with execvp

Tags: c, tree, pipe, stdin, execvp

This code basically a small part of the binary tree with nodes being processes, and it should traverse the tree inorder way passing num1 to left subtree etc. This one just creates a left child and just executes ./tpipe which is the executable of this code again. When we pass it like "./tpipe 0", scanf seems to be getting the input from the user, not the previous processes printfed string. How do I fix this? I should be using dup2 not read write etc since filedp is initated again in the beginning.

This is the cut down version :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "NEED MORE ARGUMENT\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int curDepth = atoi(argv[1]);
    int filedp[2];
    pipe(filedp);

    if (curDepth != 0)
    {
        char buf[100];
        scanf("%s", buf);
        fprintf(stderr, "buf is: %s\n", buf);
    }

    if (curDepth < 1)
    {
        int fd = fork();
        if (fd == 0)
        {
            close(filedp[0]);
            dup2(filedp[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
            dup2(filedp[0], STDIN_FILENO);
            printf("Example\n");
            char *k[] = {"./tpipe", "1", NULL};
            execvp("./tpipe", k);
        }
        else
        {
            wait(NULL); // parent
        }
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "IT IS LEAF!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `close(filedp[0])` followed by `dup2(filedp[0],STDIN_FILENO)` won't work very well. And if you remove the `close` call, you create a loop. If you want to read the child-process standard output, you should close `filedp[0]` in the child, but *not* pass it do `dup2`. Then in the parent you close `filedp[1]` and read from `filedp[0]`.

Comment: If, on the other hand, you want the child standard output to be written to the terminal, and the parent to write to the child process standard input, you do the opposite. Of course. :-)

Comment: And if you want the parent to both read from the child standard output, *and* write to the child standard input, you need *two* pipes. One for each direction.

Comment: Lastly, you need to actually read from the pipe in the parent process. Pipes have a limited buffer, and when it fills up then the writer to the pipe will become blocked. If the child process becomes blocked, and your parent process waits for the child process to end, then you have a *deadlock*. Neither the parent nor the child can continue, as they are both waiting for each other.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I'm not trying to read it from the parent tho, after execvp, I'm trying to read from new another process I can't do filedp[0]. Thats why i redirected the stdin, to read from the new process.

Comment: You have two processes: One parent and one child. One process must write to the pipe, and the other process must read from the pipe. Which process should do what?

Comment: Or do you misunderstand what the `exec` family of functions do, and think that it creates a new process? It doesn't. All it does is replace the process the function is called in, with the program specified in the `exec` call.

Comment: Or perhaps you think that the pipes will be shared between all programs you start? It won't. Each program you start will have its own separate and distinct `filedp` array. Please [edit] your question to try and give us more details about what you're trying to do. What process should read the output? What process should write the output?

Comment: child process executes the same program execvp("./tpipe", k); with that, then I try to scanf and get the string from the printf. I'm not trying to read from parent, trying to read from the child.

Comment: ok, it will have different pipe i know, but why scanf does not get the stdout file?

Comment: in child process, just trying to write before execvp and read after it in child as well. Thinking it as node, it should pass it all the way to the left nodes. If its depth would be greater etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understand it correctly, but it seems like you want the child to read `"Example\n"` on its standard input?

Then you should write it to the *pipe*. And you should write that in the *parent* process:

```
if (fd == 0)
{
    // Child process

    close(filedp[1]);  // We don't need the write-end of the pipe here

    dup2(filedp[0], STDIN_FILENO);  // Copy the read-end of the pipe to standard input

    // Then execute the program
    char *k[] = {"./tpipe", "1", NULL};
    execvp("./tpipe", k);
}
else
{
    // Parent process

    close(filedp[0]);  // We don't need the read-end of the pipe here

    write(filedp[1], "Example\n", 8);  // Write to the pipe
    // The child process will read the above from its standard input

    // Wait for the child process to exit
    wait(NULL);
}
```

Comment: this seem to work, but write  should happen exactly before the left child executes execvp, how do I make sure of that

Comment: if I do close read end then write right before the fork, it get stuck for some reason why is that?

Comment: also instead of using write function, redirecting stdout and using printf should be working but its not in this case.@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: @ÖzgürÇavuşoğlu Regarding standard out redirection, it must be done in the *parent* process, because it's the one writing to the child process. ***But*** if you do that redirection, then *everything* you write to standard output will be sent to the child process, and nothing will be written on the terminal. That's a use-case which is not common. If you want to use `printf` like functions, then I recommend [`fdopen`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fdopen.3p.html) and `fprintf`.

Comment: @ÖzgürÇavuşoğlu And why do you want to write to the pipe before there's anyone who reads it? You can do it, but you still have to remember that the pipe buffer is limited. A small string like the one in your example would work, but too much and you will block and end up with a deadlock.